# Magento 1.9 add custom button in admin order grid page

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom-button, order-grid

i need to add a custom button on admin sales order grid page like this:
[image]
I'm trying to create a module for this using this code in my config.xml file:

```
   <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <crononline>
                        <class>crononline/observer</class>
                        <method>addNewButton</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </crononline>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

and then add button by observer in this way

```
public function addNewButton($observer)
{
    $container = $observer->getBlock();
    if(null !== $container && $container->getType() == 'adminhtml/sales_order') {
        $data = array(
            'label'     => 'My button',
            'class'     => 'some-class',
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\' '  . Mage::getUrl('*/*', array('param' => 'value')) . '\')',
        );
        $container->addButton('my_button_identifier', $data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

but with no luck.
Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it works.
Here the complete files:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Module>
  </modules>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <Company_Module>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Company_Module</module>
          <frontName>companymodule</frontName>
        </args>
      </Company_Module>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        <observers>
          <unique-identifier>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>addNewButton</method>
          </unique-identifier>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

and the observer

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function addNewButton($observer)
    {   
        $container = $observer->getBlock();
        if(null !== $container && $container->getType() == 'adminhtml/sales_order') {
            $data = array(
                'label'     => 'Scarica Anagrafica',
                'class'     => '',
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''  . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('companymodule/adminhtml_controller/action') . '\')',
            );
            $container->addButton('unique-identifier', $data);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope will help someone

Answer (score 1):

Override the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order or else copy the file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order.php to app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order.php

and change the _construct function like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'sales_order';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Create New Order');
    $this->_addButton('custom_button', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Button'),
        'onclick'   => "location.href='".$this->getUrl('*/*/custombutton')."'",
        'class'     => '',
    ));
    parent::__construct();
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/create')) {
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```